# gsettings key not listed in dconf

Tags: dconf, gsettings

I wonder why in my beta of 12.10. the gsettings key `com.canonical.indicator.session` is not listed in **dconf-editor**. I can switch the value via:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session suppress-logout-restart-shutdown true
```

but cannot edit via dconf. That's strange for I remember having altered it via dconf in 12.04

Comment: the editor did not copy the command. I can change the value via "gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session suppress-logout-restart-shutdown true"

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of this is that while gconf copied the entire tree to your home directory, dconf doesn't. So there are a bunch of things that dconf-editor just doesn't see as it may or may not be in your home directory (dconf-editor only seems to work on this scope).

gsettings seems to give MUCH more consistent results...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure at which release its dconf path was changes. You can check that (I used Ubuntu 14.04 for the example):

- Check its `schema path`

  ```
  $ grep -r com.canonical.indicator.session /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
  Binary file /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/gschemas.compiled matches
  /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.indicator.session.gschema.xml:  <schema path="/apps/indicator-session/" id="com.canonical.indicator.session">
  /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.unity-greeter.gschema.xml:      <default>['ug-accessibility', 'com.canonical.indicator.keyboard', 'com.canonical.indicator.session', 'com.canonical.indicator.datetime', 'com.canonical.indicator.power', 'com.canonical.indicator.sound', 'application']</default>
  ```
- So it should be in `/apps/indicator-session/`